# Pry looking for wrong version

Tags: rvm, bundler, pry

I'm using RVM in a small repository and trying to spin up a Pry console. Pry **0.12.2** is installed as a gem in my @global gemset and not present in the repository's bundle. However, every time I run it I get

```
$ pry
Could not find proper version of pry (0.11.1) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I have tried reinstalling it, using `gem uninstall -axI`, which should have removed any executables, but no luck.

Why else might it be asking for a version that isn't present anywhere relevant?